# How can I pass the incoming response into a model in Angular?

Tags: angular, http

I have a generic service for my API requests. With this service, I can get a response from the api, but I cannot transfer the incoming data to a model or select any element from the incoming data. The error I get is

```
"Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'void'.
"
```

Lines of code that perform the relevant request inside my generic service:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpRequestService {

  constructor(
    private _http : HttpClient
  ) { }

  api: string = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/";

  setApi(api: string, differentEndpoint: boolean) {
    if(differentEndpoint)
      return api;
    else
      return this.api + api
  }
  
  
  getApi<T>(api: string, callBack: (res: HttpEvent<T>) => void, differentEndpoint: boolean = false, options : any = {}) {

    let apiUrl = this.setApi(api, differentEndpoint);
    this._http.get<T>(apiUrl, options).subscribe({
      next: (res) => callBack(res)
    })

  }
```

This is the function that is called in the relevant component.

```
getAllResults() {
    let apiEndpoint = "results"
    let resultRespoonse = this.httpRequestService.getApi(apiEndpoint, (res) => (res), false);
    resultRespoonse[0]['clientname'] // Tried this
  }
```

I made a test in this way to access the elements from the Response, but the error I got is as above. My goal is to transfer the values from the response into a model and transfer them to the html file of the relevant component. And the model of this related operation

```
export interface ResultsModel {
    "result": string,
    "ownername": string,
    "clientname": string,
    "clientid": string,
    
}
```

What part do you think is the place where I made a mistake, why can't I reach the elements in it even though the answer is received?

Answer (score 0):

I would read through Angular [Communicating with backend services using HTTP](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-a-server) docs, specifically the section I've linked. It contains good documentation on how to accomplish this.

The problem is in how you've implemented you `getApi()` and how you're calling it in `getAllResults()`. Your `getApi()` will return an `Observable`, which then needs to be subscribed to.

```
//no callback needs to be passed into this function
getApi<T>(api: string, differentEndpoint: boolean = false, options : any = {}) {
    //Build your full url
    let apiUrl = this.setApi(api, differentEndpoint);

    //execute the GET and return the response
    return this._http.get<T>(apiUrl, options)
        .pipe(map(resp => {
            //optionally modify what you want to return here
            return resp; 
        })
    );
}
```

Then you can call your function like so:

```
getAllResults() {
    let apiEndpoint = "results"
    this.httpRequestService.getApi(apiEndpoint, false).subscribe(resultResponse => {
       //Do something with the response
        alert(resultResponse[0]['clientname']);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I tried the whole code you sent, but the error I got was as follows `Property '0' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<unknown>'`